# Отправка символа "+" методом POST

Tags: jquery, post, javascript

Добрый день. С помощью аякса методом POST отправляю значение "+7 (913) 789-11-11"

```
 $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: "/aj.php",  
          data: "name="+m_data,             
          }).done(function( result ) {   alert ('good');  
        }).fail(function(result) { alert ('bad');                  
 });
```

Но почему-то приходит только  7 (913) 789-11-11, т.е. символ "+" не приходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему.

Comment: Вы перепроверили, что на момент отправки в `data:` `m_data` приходит с плюсом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, спасибо "ModaL"

джава скрипт:

```
  m_data = encodeURIComponent(m_data);
```

ПХП:

```
$newStr = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
```

Comment: @Максим147, как раз хотел об encodeURI сказать, да опередил ;)

Comment: тоже подумал было про `encodeURIComponent`, **но**: jQuery, вроде, сам urlencode'ит данные, переданные ему в `data:`. Разве нет?

Comment: нет, не делает

Answer (score 1):

Нужно на сервере обрабатывать так:

```
urlencode($_POST['name'])
```

Comment: Разницы нет :) при отправки POSTом знак "+" вообще не приходит.

Comment: Т.е. нужно его перевести в символ, и при получении на сервере преобразовать этот символ в знак "+"

Comment: @Максим147, обновил пост.

Comment: Спасибо "+" пришло. Но появилась другая проблема - символ скобочек: "+7%28903%29+930-11-11"

Comment: и вообще вся кириллица, вот слово "проверка" каким стало:   "%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%0A%0A"